# Cannot run Karma with Angular-cli

Tags: testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I encounter a strange problem that happens to one of my projects and cannot reproduce it in others even with exactly the same setup.

Every time I try to run `ng test` or the alias `npm test` I'm getting errors that two modules are missing (`karma-jasmine-html-reporter` & `karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter`). The modules though are for sure there! For example:

> web-app@0.0.3-alpha test /Users/vassilis/Projects/WebApp
>   ng test
>
> 07 03 2017 12:08:27.157:ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
>    { Error: Cannot find module 'karma-jasmine-html-reporter'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at module.exports (/Users/vassilis/Projects/WebApp/karma.conf.js:11:7)
>       at Object.parseConfig (/Users/vassilis/Projects/WebApp/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:342:5)
>       at new Server (/Users/vassilis/Projects/WebApp/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:56:20)
>       at /Users/vassilis/Projects/WebApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/test.js:26:31
>       at Class.run (/Users/vassilis/Projects/WebApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/test.js:10:16)
>       at Class.run (/Users/vassilis/Projects/WebApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/test.js:29:25)
>       at Class. (/Users/vassilis/Projects/WebApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:134:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
>   npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

This is my setup:

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And the related part in `angular-cli.json`:

```
"test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  }
```

I am really confused over here. It seems project related issue but I cannot be sure if Karma don't even run at all. Any ideas on this?

Comment: have you tried npm install --force on it?

Comment: Are you running it locally or in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies seems not installed, are you sure you've installed these dependencies?

`npm install --save-dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter`

Comment: Thanks but as I said dependencies are installed and verified. (i did several times npm installs in my attempts to find what happens and check if omething is broken in the installation).

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be too late. Remove the config entry in your angularCli like this

```
angularCli: {
  environment: 'dev'
}
//... more code
```

For more information, refer to this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc.0-update)